# Autohotkey Application Keycounter

Tags: counter, autohotkey, keystroke

I am trying to create an application based Key counter. Below is my script

```
#UseHook
KeyCount=0
#If WinActive("Ahk_Class XLMAIN") Or WinActive("Ahk_Class Notepad")
Loop
{
Input, Key, L1 I V, , 
AscKey:=Asc(Key)
If (AscKey > 31 && AscKey < 127)
KeyCount:=KeyCount+1
}
#If
^+o::
msgbox %KeyCount%
return
```

As the WinActive commands says it should count keystrokes if active window is either Excel or notepad. But this script counts all keystrokes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `#IfWinActive` instead of `#If WinActive("blahblah")`. see Docs [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the #if its only for hotkeys and hotstrings but you can use a normal if statment like this

```
#UseHook
KeyCount=0


Loop
{
    Input, Key, L1 I V
    If (WinActive("Ahk_Class XLMAIN") Or WinActive("Ahk_Class Notepad"))
    {
        AscKey:=Asc(Key)
        If (AscKey > 31 && AscKey < 127)
        KeyCount++
    }
}


^+o::
msgbox %KeyCount%
return
```

Hope it helps